# How to make bootstrap row "col-md-4" fullscreen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap grid system, but can't seem to make the rows full-screen size. Right now i'm getting something like this:

```
|    | col-md4 | | col-md4 | | col-md4 |    |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
```

I want it too take all the space of the screen like this, so there is not white space in the left and right side.

```
|      col-md4 | | col-md4 | | col-md4      |
|                                           |
```

Have read something that it is because it's inside an container, but when i remove that, it is just the same. I'm using the bootstrap.css file and my own site.css file.

**Code:**

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="images/spise.png" />
            <br />
            Some text here
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="images/tid.png" />
            <br />
            Some text here
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <img src="images/tv.png" />
            <br />
            Some text here
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

**CSS:**

```
.col-lg-4 {
    height: 200px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;   
    background-color: #3498db;
}
```

Also, i'm trying to make the text and icon the my col-md-4 div class too auto it self in the middle. But this does also not work properly.

**UPDATED**

Here is a picture of how it looks like:

[image]

Here you can see that it is not fullsize compared to my bootstrap carousel.

**UPDATED 2: (Masterpage code)**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Mandersen_Hotels.Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" runat="server">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/default.aspx">M-Hotels&nbsp;
                <div class="IconFront">
                    <asp:Image class="img1" ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="28px" ImageUrl="Icon.png" Width="30px" ImageAlign="Right" />
                </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Booking.aspx">Booking</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/User.aspx">User</a></li>
                </ul>
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Registration.aspx">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Login.aspx">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a runat="server" href="~/User.aspx" title="Manage your account">Hello,!</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a runat="server" href="~/default.aspx" title="Log out"></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - M-Hotels A/S</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It takes full space: http://www.bootply.com/eizUrPaMKE

Comment: @Mikkel - which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Maybe you can share a link to your page? With inspecting the code it would be easier to understand your problem. Or does this run on your local environment?

Comment: maybe you can post the html output. the parts you posted do not cause the whitespace.

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.4 , and right now it runs in a local environment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mikkel**, Hi there, try using `text-center`class like this.

**Added to this post**

I have set up a **[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/unut79bt/embedded/result/)** to do what you are looking for.

I wrapped the image and text in a div and centered it both ways.

```
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;  
}
```

Comment: No. didn't do anything too it.. have taken a picture.. will upload it now.

Comment: text-center is to center your **text**.

Comment: Yes, but i have already done that with my css code: text-align: center; i want the icon + text to auto itself both vertically and horizonally.

Comment: I give it a try.. 2 sec :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the `.container-fluid` is the part with the blue background. This element is not the problem. The whitespace is caused by the `container body-content` in your masterpage. Try removing this div or at least the container class.

For future problems of this kind, please try to use the devtools of your browser ([Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Tools), [IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bg182326(v=vs.85)))

Comment: If i remove the .container-fluid, it will just be the same.. something is blocking it..

Comment: i think you didn't understand my answer. i meant to say you have to remove the elements around the container. the code that you posted is not the cause of the whitespace

Comment: That could be the case. But without the HTML around the container it is impossible to know what causes the whitespace

Comment: updated my answer with reference to your master page

Comment: It worked.. thanks man.. now i see the point in all this.. have to take a closer look at my masterpage :P

Comment: @Mikkel just curious: why did you accept the other answer if my answer was the one that solved your problem?